# Replace second and last second characters, using re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `"F(foo)"`, and I'd like to replace that string with `"F('foo')"`. I know we can also use regular expression in the second parameter and do this replacement using `re.sub(r"F\(foo\)", r"F\('foo'\)",str)`. But the problem here is, foo is a dynamic string variable. It is different every time we want to do this replacement. Is it possible by some sort of regex, to do such replacement in a cleaner way?

I remember one way to extract foo using `()` and then `.group(1)`. But this would require me to define one more temporary variable just to store foo. I'm curious if there is a way by which we can replace `"F(foo)"` with `"F('foo')"` in a single line or in other words in a more cleaner way.

Examples :

`F(name)` should be replaced with `F('name')`.
`F(id)` should be replaced with `F('id')`.
G(name) should not be replaced.
So, the regex would be `r"F\((\w)+\)"` to find such strings.

Comment: You might not need regular expressions. Is it the case that you want quote marks after and before the opening and closing parentheses respectively?

Comment: You could potentially just do a string replace here. Could you give some more samples of your data so it's clearer if regex is actually required

Comment: do you want to remove `s =` from the string?

Comment: That can't be done, because in the string, I only want to do such replacement where there is `F(foo)`. We should keep `()` or `G()` as it is. @gmds

Comment: @j.doe `s =` is not part of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.sub`

Ex:

```
import re

s = "F(foo)"
print(re.sub(r"\((.*)\)", r"('\1')", s))
```

**Output:**

```
F('foo')
```

Comment: why are you using `?` after `.*`?

Answer (score 0):

The following regex encloses valid [Python|C|Java] identifiers after F and in parentheses in single quotation marks:

```
re.sub(r"F\(([_a-z][_a-z0-9]+)\)", r"F('\1')", s, flags=re.I)
#"F('foo')"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, depending on what foo actually is.
If it can't contain `(` or `)`, you can just replace `(` with `('` and `)` with `')`. Otherwise, try using

```
re.sub(r"F\((.*)\)", r"F('\1')", yourstring)
```

where the `\1` in the replacement part will reference the `(.*)` capture group in the search regex

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern `F\((\w)+\)` you are almost there, you just need to put the quantifier `+` after the `\w` to repeat matching 1+ word characters.

If you put it after the capturing group, you repeat the group which will give you the value of the last iteration in the capturing group which would be the second `o` in foo.

You could update your expression to:

```
F\((\w+)\)
```

And in the replacement refer to the capturing group using `\1`

```
F('\1')
```

For example:

```
import re
str = "F(foo)"
print(re.sub(r"F\((\w+)\)", r"F('\1')", str)) # F('foo')
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/xkQFUp)